# test cases are shown in all the groups of groups array in testng even if single group is included in test run

Tags: java, testng

I want to get test cases according to the browser used in test report so i m using

this in testng

```
<test name="TestFirefox">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
        <parameter name="version" value="54.0" />
        <parameter name="platform" value="WINDOWS" />
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="Init" />
                <include name="a" />
                <include name="b" />
                <include name="c-Firefox" />
                <include name="RunReport" />

            </run>      
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.InitAndCleanUp" />
            <class name="com.TestLogin" />
            <class name="com.TestUserRegistration" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->

    <test name="TestChrome">

        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <parameter name="version" value="58.0" />
        <parameter name="platform" value="WINDOWS" />
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="Init" />
                <include name="a" />
                <include name="b" />
                <include name="c-chrome" />
                <include name="RunReport" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.InitAndCleanUp" />
            <class name="com.TestLogin" />
            <class name="com.TestUserRegistration" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->


    <test name="TestSafari">


        <parameter name="browser" value="safari" />
        <parameter name="version" value="6.0" />
        <parameter name="platform" value="MAC" />


        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="Init" />
                <include name="a" />
                <include name="b" />
                <include name="c-safari" /> 
                <include name="RunReport" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.InitAndCleanUp" />
            <class name="com.TestLogin" />
            <class name="com.TestUserRegistration" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
```

but it shows every test in every group of c

how to show only one type of test cases under one group like ran on firefox under c-firefox only not others

i tried using script in testng under methodexecuter but same problem was there

right now i m looking to change group name dynamically or at run time